# dreamweaver installation help.

Tags: dreamweaver

Hi here my quick question. I installed dreamweaver CS5 recently to my new machine and by mistake I haven't selected PHP file type when dreamweaver starts first time. Now if I have a php file it is showing text file icon rather than dreamweaver icon. If I click open with option and set open with dreamweaver always still I see no icon of dreamweaver in file.

Is there any way to reset file types in dreamweaver CS5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is a more a windows file association issue rather than anything to do with Dreamweaver.

If you want to associate PHP files with DW this might help  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with Steve, however, if you aren't able to open said PHP files in Dreamweaver. You can try this to add the file type in dreamweaver.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/dreamweaver/ig/Dreamweaver-Options/File-Types-and-Editors.htm